# Make image move per tile pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to create a 2D tile based game. I have already managed to move my soldier freely over the tiles, but now I would like to make it move per tile on a keypress.

I know when I change self.pos to self.x or self.y I can move the soldier freely over the screen

My code so far:

```
#envoirment variables
ice = 0
forest = 1
desert = 2
swamp = 3
water = 4
island = 5

#envoirement tiles
tiles = {
        ice    : icetile,
        forest : foresttile, 
        desert : deserttile,
        swamp  : swamptile,
        water  : watertile,
        island : islandtile        
    }

#tilemap
tilemap = [
        [ 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [ 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [ 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [ 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [ 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [ 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [ 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [ 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        [ 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        [ 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        [ 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
        [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
       ]
class Soldier(object):

        def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("soldier.png")
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.hp = 1
        self.ap = 1
        self.price = 150
        self.pos = [0, 0]

    def keys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.pos[1] += 1
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.pos[1] -= 1
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.pos[0] += 1
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.pos[0] -= 1

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))

def gameloop():

gamescreen = pygame.display.set_mode((mapwidth*tilesize, mapheight*tilesize))  
gameloop = True
soldier = Soldier()
kasteel = Base()


while gameloop: #Main game loop
    for row in range(mapheight):
        for column in range(mapwidth):
            gamescreen.blit(tiles[tilemap[row][column]], (column*tilesize, row*tilesize))


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        print(pos)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            gameloop = False

    soldier.keys()
    kasteel.draw(gamescreen)
    soldier.draw(gamescreen)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(40) 
pygame.quit()
```

Thank you for your time and helping me

PS:any recommendation for a book or website are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

What you will want to do here is keep track of the first frame on which a key is depressed, and call a move function when that happens. This could be done as follows:

```
def keys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN] and not self.prev_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.row += 1
        if key[pygame.K_UP] and not self.prev_pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.row -= 1
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT] and not self.prev_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.col -= 1
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT] and not self.prev_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.col += 1

        self.prev_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN] = key[pygame.K_DOWN]
        self.prev_pressed[pygame.K_UP] = key[pygame.K_UP]
        self.prev_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT] = key[pygame.K_LEFT]
        self.prev_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT] = key[pygame.K_RIGHT]
```

where `prev_pressed` is initialized to all false at construction. Instead of storing `pos`, `x`, and `y` instead store `row` and `col` as the current row and column of the soldier in the tile array. When it comes time to printing, map the tile in the array to pixels on the screen. For instance, if each tile is 50 pixels wide and 50 pixels tall, the corresponding pixel on the screen for some tile would be `50*row, 50*col`.

Answer (score 0):

surface.blit(self.image, (self.POS[0]* tilesize, self.POS[1]* tilesize))

Sorry for capitals, am at work and posting on lousy tablet.